# What happens if I install Packages twice?

Tags: apt, package-management, email, postfix

just want to know what happens if I install a Package twice.

Is it just gonna remove the old one? I purged postfix and it deleted some other files with it, but im not sure which belong to which package.

Here is a snippet of the Apt logs:

Original Apt-Get (before the Purge):

```
Start-Date: 2015-11-22  12:53:25
        Commandline: apt-get install tmux mailutils postfix lib32gcc1 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386
        Install: libmailutils4:amd64 (2.99.98-1.1, automatic), libevent-2.0-5:amd64 (2.0.21-stable-1ubuntu1.14.04.1, automatic), gcc-4.8-base:i386 (4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04, automatic), tmux:amd64 (1.8-5), postfix:amd64 (2.11.0-1ubuntu1), lib32gcc1:amd64 (4.9.1-0ubuntu1), libgc1c2:amd64 (7.2d-5ubuntu2, automatic), libfribidi0:amd64 (0.19.6-1, automatic), libgcc1:i386 (4.9.1-0ubuntu1, automatic), libc6:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.6,$
        Remove: sendmail:amd64 (8.14.4-4.1ubuntu1), sendmail-bin:amd64 (8.14.4-4.1ubuntu1)
        End-Date: 2015-11-22  12:53:57
```

Purge + Autoremove:

```
Start-Date: 2015-11-23  10:21:29
        Commandline: apt-get purge postfix
        Purge: bsd-mailx:amd64 (8.1.2-0.20131005cvs-1ubuntu0.14.04.1), postfix:amd64 (2.11.0-1ubuntu1), logwatch:amd64 (7.4.0+svn20130529rev144-1ubuntu1), sensible-mda:amd64 (8.14.4-4.1ubuntu1), mailutils:amd64 (2.99.98-1.1)
        End-Date: 2015-11-23  10:21:41

Start-Date: 2015-11-23  10:23:10
    Commandline: apt-get autoremove
    Remove: libmailutils4:amd64 (2.99.98-1.1), sendmail-cf:amd64 (8.14.4-4.1ubuntu1), libgc1c2:amd64 (7.2d-5ubuntu2), libfribidi0:amd64 (0.19.6-1), libdate-manip-perl:amd64 (6.42-1), guile-2.0-libs:amd64 (2.0.9+1-1ubuntu1), liblzo2-2:amd64 (2.06-1.2ubuntu1.1), mysql-common:amd64 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2), mailutils-common:amd64 (2.99.98-1.1), libkyotocabinet16:amd64 $
    End-Date: 2015-11-23  10:23:14
```

I'd like to just run the `apt-get install tmux mailutils postfix lib32gcc1 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386` Command again, but will this interfere if for example tmux is already installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `tmux` is already installed, it will just mark it as "manually installed" (and not as an automatic install due to a dependence) so that it will not appears any more in the list of auto-removable packages.

If it's installed and there is a newer version available, it will do an upgrade (unless the package is held, in which case things are more complex).

Normally installing a package that is already installed is a no-op (minus the things above) unless you use `--reinstall` or ask for a very specific version.

```
[romano:~] % sudo apt-get install firefox
[sudo] password for romano: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
firefox is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Anyway, if you have a doubt about what `apt-get` will do, you can run it with the option `-s` (it stands for *simulate*) and it will tell you what it would do without effectively doing anything (you can leave the `sudo` out, too):

```
[romano:~] % apt-get -s install tmux     
NOTE: This is only a simulation!
      apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
      Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
      so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tmux
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
Inst tmux (1.8-5 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
Conf tmux (1.8-5 Ubuntu:14.04/trusty [amd64])
```

Comment: okay thank you! I'll just run the installation again then.